# Not much community on this site for new members

Tags: discussion, new-users

I joined this community because I often visited MSE when I wanted to find ideas for the intuition behind theorems and definitions. Currently I'm a mathematics graduate student and I often feel that the beauty and intuition behind results falls short in the lectures I attend. On this site there are thoughtful and detailed discussions on these issues that helped me understand important concepts.

However now that I joined I find that people with low reputation are often not treated with respect. We get one-liner answers and these often in the comments. As if to say that my question is not even worthy of a real reply. People sometimes don't even bother reading the question properly before commenting a dismissive 'answer'. Downvotes without explanation that feel like little more than a middle finger to the face if you put effort into your question. The comments, while not fulfilling the strict definition of abusive, still feel degrading in their air of superiority. It reminds me more of some exclusive gentlemen's club, administered by and for PhDs, than of a community interested in helping one another.

Of course there are many exceptions to what I just wrote. Kind people that give great answers or constructive criticism. After all there is a reason I joined.

But often I wish people would just ignore posts instead of making unhelpful comments or replies.
And downvotes without any explanation, on a post that took effort to make, don't say *'please improve your post'* but rather *'I don't want you here'*.

Comment: I have added the tag ([meta-tag:new-users]) since it seems relevant to the topic of the question. I was a bit unsure whether ([meta-tag:down-votes]) should be added.

Comment: Community moderation is a responsibility we all share.  When your Readers suggest you improve your posts in specific ways, they are engaging with you to help create content that will have lasting value, in addition of course to helping you with learning math in the short term.   Setting as a goal "often I wish people would just ignore posts" might be self-defeating, but certainly it is inconsistent with the responsibility many of us feel to be helpful.

Comment: Have you checked out the Chat Rooms? That sounds more like what you're looking for. I frequently see people just talking about what's up in their lives there.  And maybe some of the chat room regulars could recommend particular rooms that would fit best?

Comment: Internet forums do not lend themselves to sensitivity to context. I do not think it has much to do with credentialism; the kind of attitude you talk about can come from anywhere and can sometimes be misinterpreted because of text limits on comments and a need to get to a point. Although I do sometimes read comments and wonder "why did they bother to say that?" There is good stuff too. Upvote the things you like, ignore the things you don't, downvote toxicity (frankly this is quite rare on Math.SE, relative to the rest of the Internet). It will make the community better.

Comment: A sense of belonging within a community is a two-way street, developed over mutual interactions, whether comments, answers, questions, reviewing, or in chatrooms.  Having been here 60 days may not be sufficient to feel fully connected to the community.  The learning curve on this site, like in any new community, may seem steep.  But it will not help you to focus on all the others that you believe have failed you; rather, how you can interact with others, and give to the communitity, what you expect it to give back to you.

Comment: Also, be aware that voting on the meta site means only "I agree with you" or "I disagree with you".  Votes here are not judgements, nor do they impact your rep.  It says a lot about your character and determination, to post on meta.  And, let me say "Welcome!!  You are just as much a member of this community as anyone else.  You've both asked *and* answered questions, and today you posted on meta. You're far more bold than I was initially, after joining this site a decade ago.  I spent months just sitting on the sidelines ...

Comment: ....until I gathered to nerve to post answers.  Just give it time; you've done a lot within the short time you've been on this site.

Comment: +1 to the query, from (-9) back to (-8).  The only thing that you can control is whether you wish to accept the general behavior of mathSE reviewers, as is, and still find a way to positively influence them.  If you  are interested in that, see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Re: one line answers in comments. I usually give a one-line answer in comments when the problem is (for me) relatively straightforward, and likely a duplicate but which I cannot find or don't have time to search. It's basically a way of giving quick feedback that almost certainly will solve the issue, or point out a major issue. Often it's not because the question "is not worth a real reply", but because the content of the answer is too limited to be worth a long reply.

Comment: Don’t attribute malice where you can something something razor...personally I leave comments sometimes because comments are easier to write than answers. Try to remember that you aren’t owed an answer by joining, people aren’t paid to write an answer for you and they read enough of your post to think that a comment would be helpful even if they were spirited and even if they were wrong. I peeked a little at your posts and you seem to be doing very well. Also ‘most’ posts aren’t received so enthusiastically, but you have naturally seen the higher voted ones that search will find for you...