# How I can Get reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, images, privileges

I used to write my answer in image,
But when I want to post it, it said need 10 reputations

How do I must write?

Comment: Images ought to be avoided. Type your question using MathJax instead.

Comment: I imagine that if you posted answers with images as substitute of text, you would end up losing reputation.

Comment: What is "math jax"?

Comment: See [this MathJax link](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: See [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for what the title asks.  It is recommended to take the site tour and familiarize yourself with the Help Center before asking here on Meta.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrIPxlFzDi0

Answer (score 13):

To be clear, "MathJax" is a version of "TeX" or "LaTeX", which is the current professional standard for typesetting mathematics. It's a little goofy, but not so hard to learn for writing basic mathematical things. In any case, if you are wanting to pursue mathematics, being able to write/typeset things in this way is an absolute essential.

In particular, on MathStackExchange, and elsewhere, people do not like "images", for several reasons. First, they involve external links, which are an un-necessary danger. Second, the link can get broken. Third, often the image is hard to read (especially for people with visual difficulties).

Also, screen-shot+paste-image is a reeeeeally low-effort way to ask a question, and the general style here is to demonstrate some self-effort at addressing the question you want to ask. An image is rather negative evidence of effort. :)

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742) also for many good reasons to avoid images.