# I want to understand as to why my question was downvoted.

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Need to compute the conditional expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879421/need-to-compute-the-conditional-expectation)

I have received two downvotes for this question. I am a new user to this platform, and this was just my second question. I thought that I had made my question precise and amply clear. However, my question has received two downvotes. No reasons have been provided for the same. I am quite perplexed as to why that has happened. Furthermore, just because of one question that has received two downvotes, I have been barred from asking questions for the next two days. I even dropped a comment requesting for the reason for downvoting. I am even willing enough to improve upon the quality of my question. Please guide me as to how those downvotes could be removed. I have more questions in my mind, and if I am periodically banned from asking questions, then I am afraid that I might not even be able to make use of this platform.

Comment: Your question is clear, but your working is kind of hazy. You do not explain, for example, what made you calculate the conditional PDF. What likely made you do that is a previous example of some sort, which you could cite. Or mention the textbook you're reading so others can understand your thought process. Maybe there's another problem that you needed to look at in the same book instead, which gives the technique needed to solve this problem (rather than the one you thought might work). Context is not just what you did/what you think is important but why it's important as well

Comment: Having said that, the question doesn't seem to be a duplicate, and there aren't any close votes so far, so you still have a chance to make that question better. I think question bans can be reversed if your present questions get voted up sufficiently, so you have incentive to do that. ( May I also add : the conditional PDF is given, but *how* it was derived, the details are missing. If that was written down it'd make things better too).

Comment: Also, I request feedback to better understand why this particular post of mine has received two downvotes, and how it can be improved.

Comment: Can't explain that, but did you try to use the pointers at [this post?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Is it alright if I rewrite the entire question and leave a note that I have changed the original question? I am talking about the conditional expectation question.

Comment: If it's a separate question please don't do this. If it's the same question, but you have some more context to add, then you should do it. If you have any other math questions, consider improving your questions which are already on the site (and increasing their vote count, like the conditional expectation one) before your ban is expired/revoked.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I have edited my question. If possible, can you please have a look at it, provide feedback, and take necessary action?

Comment: One downvoted question does not get you a question-ban. Your other posts are contributing to that - they also need fixing before you are able to post again. Removing irrelevant meta commentary from the post is a start, leaving just the mathematics to be voted on.

Comment: @Nij However, I have only posted two questions on Mathematics Stack Exchange so far. My first question received zero downvotes and zero upvotes. My second question received two downvotes, which have also been withdrawn now that I have edited the question. However, the question ban still remains for a period of 48 hours. How can my other posts contribute to the question ban when I have only posted two questions?

Comment: For what it's worth, virtually no MathSE posted question that I have seen (from me or anyone else) that followed 
[this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
has been downvoted. Instead, such questions are almost always upvoted, with 
MathSE reviewers going out of their way to try to answer the question.  I am not saying that I agree with the standards, or agree with others' negative reactions.  What I am saying is that you can use the linked protocol article to prevent downvotes.